# Replacing an instance declaration

Tags: class, haskell, instance

I would like to replace an instance declaration of a standard type of Haskell library. For example, replacing the `Show` instance for boolean by :

```
instance Show Bool where
  show True  = "Vrai"
  show False = "Faux"
```

But when I try to do it, I get this error :

```
Duplicate instance declarations:
  instance Show Bool -- Defined at Exemples01.hs:37:10
  instance Show Bool -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
```

**Is it possible to replace an instance declaration with Haskell ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell instances are meant to be unique: there should be only one instance per type, in the whole program.

Orphan modules can temporarily break uniqueness. Orphans are modules declaring an instance for a type, but not declaring the type not the class. In principle, two modules can import the same type from a third module and declare different instances for it. This "works" until a fourth module tries to import from both, causing a clash between the two instances which triggers a compiler error. So, in practice, uniqueness is still eventually guaranteed.

Most instances for standard types are not declared in orphans, so you can not avoid to import them when you import the standard type. Hence, you are stuck with the standard instance.

There are some Haskell extensions such as `OverlappingInstances` and `IncoherentInstances` which can break the instance uniqueness. I believe most Haskellers consider this to be a wart in the system, and not something to actively exploit. Indeed, when multiple instances are present for the same type, it is no longer clear how the compiler will choose. This makes the code very fragile, so I'd recommend not to attempt to break instance uniqueness.